# How do I check the screen size of a macbook pro retina?

Tags: macbook

My aunt plans to purchase a cover for her Macbook Pro and she is not sure about the screen size. I think that it is 15 inch but I am not sure and would like to verify.
Does About My Mac show the screen size in Mavericks?

I don't physically have access to the laptop and therefore need a couple of quick steps which can be told over a phone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do this easily by getting the serial number of the Mac, which can be found in "About my Mac," and entering it within Apples Warranty and Support Page - https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do -

Answer (score 7):

1. Click on the apple logo on the top left corner
2. Click on "About this Mac"
3. Click on "Display"

You should have the specs of your display.

Answer (score 1):

Check [About This Mac](http://www.everymac.com/mac-identification/where-to-find-apple-model-identifiers-model-id-machine-model-for-identification.html) info under apple menu and find model identifier. Search for details of your Mac machine from [everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/by_capability/mac-specs-by-machine-model-machine-id.html) using model identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Take the model number and search the 'net: "Model Number" + specs.